# Make Regex stop looking at \n

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string:

```
"\t Product:         ces DEVICE TYPE \nSometext" //between ":" and "ces" are 9 white spaces
```

I need to parse the part "DEVICE TYPE". I'm trying to do this with Regex. I use this expression, which works.

```
((?<=\bProduct:)(\W+\w+){3}\b)
```

this expression returns:

```
"         ces DEVICE TYPE"
```

The problem is here: Some devices have a string like this:

```
"\t Product:         ces DEVICETYPE \nSometext"
```

If I use the same expression to parse the device type I get this as result:

```
"         ces DEVICETYPE \nSometext"
```

How do I get my regex to stop when a \n is found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
(?<=ces)[^\\n]+
```

If all you want is what's after ces and before \n that is..

Answer (score 2):

In .NET you can use `RegexOptions.Multiline`.  This changes the behaviour of `^` and `$`.
Rather than meaning the start and end of your string, they now mean start and end of any line within your string.

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<=\bProduct:).+$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You could use:**

```
(?m)((?<=\bProduct:).+)
```

Explanation:

```
(?m)((?<=\bProduct:).+)

Match the remainder of the regex with the options: ^ and $ match at line breaks (m) «(?m)»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «((?<=\bProduct:).+)»
   Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=\bProduct:)»
      Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
      Match the characters “Product:” literally «Product:»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»


or

    ((?<=\bProduct:)[^\r\n]+)
```

**Explanation**

```
((?<=\bProduct:)[^\r\n]+)

Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «((?<=\bProduct:)[^\r\n]+)»
   Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=\bProduct:)»
      Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
      Match the characters “Product:” literally «Product:»
   Match a single character NOT present in the list below «[^\r\n]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      A carriage return character «\r»
      A line feed character «\n»
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer :) the second regex works if you change [^\r\n] to [^\\r\\n] or [^\\n]